# How can one calculate the probability that any line is on lattice point?

Tags: probability

In plane coordinates, how can one calculate the probability that any line is on lattice point? 
If you add set theory grounds about solving this problem, I would be very thankful.
I am a korean highschooler. I'm sorry that my English is so poor.

Comment: What are your own thoughts about the problem? On what grounds do you choose this line?

Comment: probability is 0

Comment: choosing depends on only random. I think that it would be 0. because in case that slope and y-intercept are e(exponential), it isn't on lattice point. cause irrational number set is larger than rational number set, I think that because of many irrational number, it would be 0.

Comment: to Kenta .  why?

Comment: Probability requires a probability distribution. There is no uniform probability distribution over the entire plane, so we have to choose something else. A random point in the square $[0,1]\times[0,1],$ and a line at a random angle through that point, might be suitable. Are you familiar with Buffon's needle problem?